# how to make custom dots for react-native-carousel

Tags: react-native, pagination, carousel, react-native-flatlist, react-animated

I have to create pagination dots for a carousel as follows:
The active dot should be a gradient color, inactive dots to be a grey color
[here is active dot's design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuieL.png)

when user starts sliding, the current active dot transitions from a white to grey color. I am having problems working on this part. [design for dots when sliding starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCnCT.png)

what I have tried so far is:

```
const renderCarouselDots = () => {
return (
   <View style={styles.dotsView}>
    <FlatList
      style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}
      horizontal
      data={carouselData}
      renderItem={({item, index}) =>
        activeSlide === index ? (
          isSliderSwiping ? (
            <View style={[styles.carouselDot, {backgroundColor: "white"}]}></View>
          ) : (
            <GradientBackground style={styles.carouselDot} />
          )
        ) : (
          <View
            style={[styles.carouselDot, styles.inactiveCarouselDot]}></View>
        )
      }
    />
  </View>
);};
```

and the code for carousel is:

```
 <Carousel
        // onScroll={() => console.log("scroll start")}
        renderItem={renderCarouselItem}
        data={carouselData}
        sliderWidth={getScreenWidthHeight().width}
        itemWidth={getScreenWidthHeight().width}
        onBeforeSnapToItem={(i) => setIsSwiping(true)}
        onSnapToItem={(index) => {
          setActiveSlide(index);
          setIsSwiping(false);
          console.log(index);
        }}
        // onScrollBeginDrag={(e) => console.log(e)}
        // autoplay
      />
      {renderCarouselDots()}
```

What I've achieved so far...
[dots when there is no sliding etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uhaW.png) and
[dots sometime after sliding starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM3Ex.jpg)

I know how to animate between colors. But I am unsure how to know when the user has started swiping, I have tried using the **onBeforeSnapToItem** property, so that I could turn the dot into a white view on slide, but this triggers way after sliding starts.

I'd like to know how to achieve this animation between gradient to white and grey dot, and when to call this animation. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
onItemSwipe = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
  // below variable will give active index of the item that is visible
  const _activeSlide = Math.floor(parseInt(nativeEvent.contentOffset.x) / parseInt(nativeEvent.layoutMeasurement.width));


  // as it is onMomentumScrollEnd this activeSlide will only change on complete scroll change
  this.setState({
    activeSlide_: _activeSlide,
  });
};

<FlatList {...otherProps} onMomentumScrollEnd={this.onItemSwipe} />
```